# Which actions do shopkeepers consider hostile?

Tags: spelunky-hd

In one of my recent Spelunky runs, I had an item that allowed me to see gems embedded in the ground/walls. Two particularly lucrative gems were embedded in a shop's ceiling, and I assumed the shopkeeper would not begrudge me giving him a new skylight. Boy was I wrong.

Seeing how I do not consider being murdered by shopkeepers a good way to end a run, I would like to know which actions they consider hostile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shop-keepers frown on the following actions:

- Removing items from their shop without their consent
- Carrying out mining operations in the near vicinity of their shop
- Refurbishing their shops without a work permit
- Handling live explosives while inside their shops
- Assaulting the shop-keepers or their staff
- Targetting the shop-keepers or their staff with flying or falling objects
- Abducting the shop-keepers' staff
- Photography
- Bowling a huge boulder through their shops
- Unsolicited visits when at home (vault)
- Unwrapping presents early

The shop-keepers come from a single family and word gets around fast underground. Any report of misdeeds by the spelunker or any of his associates, the inhabitants of the mine, will be met with swift and fair shotgun justice.

Comment: That seems pretty comprehensive. There's one specific scenario I want to be sure about, though. Let us say I have a monster with me inside a shop (this actually happened to me). Am I allowed to whip it, or shoot it with a projectile weapon, or both? After merely throwing a bomb cost me my life once, I didn't feel like giving any of these a try and usually try to stomp said monsters.

Comment: As long as you don't hit a damsel or hired hand on sale or the shop-keeper you should be fine.

Comment: OK, I have to say, this sounds like one darn strange game.  In fact, this description sound so odd that I feel inspired to find it and try it out ...

Comment: Shopkeepers will also get angry if they take any damage from any source at all that a player could cause, even if it's a monster that did it.  Shopkeepers will blame the spelunker for explosions from frogs, boomerangs, falling or thrown items, and any number of other things, even if they weren't directly caused by him.